# Hot reload on save

Tags: macos, vim, flutter, hot-reload

I'm currently using a terminal and vim on OSX as a development environment for Flutter. Things are going pretty well except that the app does not reload when I save any dart files. Is there a way to trigger that behavior?Currently I have to go to the terminal and hit "r" to see my changes.

Comment: A link I got from Danny Tuppeny https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/35ad2a786dd92ab3343f55e53b069c433d81895b/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/commands/run.dart#L152

Comment: There is a more complex service API that allows to execute all kind of commands and queries. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/doc/daemon.md (link also from Danny)

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for the plug, but I wrote a very simple [plugin](https://github.com/reisub0/hot-reload.vim) to handle this.

It makes use of Flutter's `--pid-file` command line flag to send it a `SIGUSR1` signal.

You can achieve the same result as my two-line plugin by adding this to an `autocmd`

```
silent execute '!kill -SIGUSR1 "$(cat /tmp/flutter.pid)"'
```

And launching Flutter with the `--pid-file` flag.

Comment: good starting point! I made a plugin [hankchiutw/flutter-reload.vim](https://github.com/hankchiutw/flutter-reload.vim) based on this but no need to use `--pid-file` flag. Feel free to give it a try!

Comment: @HankChiu I'm on atom. Can you please tell me how to trigger hot reload whenever there is a change to the file?

Comment: @AdnanBadshah Have you tried [atom-flutter](https://github.com/dart-atom/atom-flutter)?

Answer (score 2):

I made a vim plugin [hankchiutw/flutter-reload.vim](https://github.com/hankchiutw/flutter-reload.vim) based on killing with `SIGUSR1`.

You don't have to use `--pid-file` flag with this plugin. (Thanks to the `pgrep` :))

Simply execute `flutter run`, modify your *.dart file and see the reloading.

Comment: hey @hank-chiu, im trying out your plugin now. i have a pane open in tmux with flutter run in it and another pane with vim. when i save, its not refreshing. am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I did it with the excellent little tool called `entr`. On OS/X you can install it from `brew`: `brew install entr`. The home page of the tool is at http://eradman.com/entrproject/

Then you start `flutter run` with the pidfile as [@nobody_nowhere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4398309/nobody-nowhere) suggests.

How do you run `entr` depends on the level of service. In the simplest case you just do `find lib/ -name '*.dart' | entr -p kill -USR1 $(cat /tmp/flutter.pid)`

But such invocation will not detect new files in the source tree (because `find` builds a list of files to watch only once, at the start). You can get away with slightly more complex one-liner:

```
while true
do
    find lib/ -name '*.dart' | \
        entr -d -p kill -USR1 $(cat /tmp/flutter.pid)
done
```

The `-d` option makes `entr` exit when it does detect a new file in one of the directories and the loop runs again.

I personally use even more complex approach. I use Redux and change to middleware or other state files does not work with hot reload, it doesn't pick up these changes. So you need to resort to hot restart.
I have a script `hotrestarter.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail
PIDFILE="/tmp/flutter.pid"

if [[ "${1-}" != "" && -e $PIDFILE ]]; then
    if [[ "$1" =~ \/state\/ ]]; then
        kill -USR2 $(cat $PIDFILE)
    else
        kill -USR1 $(cat $PIDFILE)
    fi
fi
```

It checks if the modified file lives in `/state` subdirectory and if true does hot restart or else hot reload. I call the script like that:

```
while true
do
    find lib/ -name '*.dart' | entr -d -p ./hotreloader.sh /_
done
```

The `/_` parameter makes `entr` to pass the name of the file to the program being invoked.

Answer (score -1):

You don't say what platform, but all platforms have a "watcher" app that can run a command when any file in a tree changes.  You'll need to run one of those.

Answer (score -2):

vscode has this feature. If you don't mind moving to vscode you can get it out of the box. You could also reach out to the author and see if they have any suggestions on how you could do it in vim or check the source directly. Most likely vim will have a mechanism to do so.

Comment: I've actually spent a lot of time customizing VIM to make migration worthy at this point. I hope Flutter can bring its tooling on par with react-native which currently supports hot-reloading on save.