# How to edit flutter project with emacs?

Tags: emacs, process, flutter, signals, hot-reload

> INFO: I'm a Emacs user used to develop mobile apps with react-native.

## Description

*Recently, I'm trying to develop a flutter app, stuck with the `hot-reload` part, I hope that flutter can reload automatically when I make changes to `lib/*dart`.*

**What I am thinking about is watching the `lib/*dart`'s modification, as it happen, passing a `r` to the flutter process automatically.**

How can I reach the `flutter run` process?

## Solution

**Emacs Solution**

After reading [Hot reload on save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340508/hot-reload-on-save) over and over again, I updated my Emacs' configuration file:

```lisp
(require 'dart-mode)
(defun auto-reload ()
  (shell-command "kill -s SIGUSR1 $(cat /tmp/flutter.pid) && echo 'reload flutter...'"))

(add-hook 'dart-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'auto-reload nil 'make-it-local)))
```

It's quite easy, that I can't believe it...kill the `flutter run` process, and it will reload automatically, after sending signal `kill -SIGUSR1` to `flutter run` process through our shell-script.

Thanks @pskink, I had took my brain and tried again, then, the problem has been solved.

I checked the [description](https://linux.die.net/man/7/signal) about `linux signal` again, the `kill` command described as:

> Sends a signal to a specified process, to all members of a specified process group, or to all processes on the system.

Not just rudely killing processes...and here is the description of `kill` in command-line:

```
kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec
...or
kill -l [sigspec]
```

However, the flag `--pid-file` of **flutter** is described like this:

> Specify a file to write the process id to. You can send SIGUSR1 to trigger a hot reload and SIGUSR2 to trigger a hot restart.

We `kill -SIGUSR1 $(cat /tmp/flutter.pid)`, as we send signal `SIGURS1` to the `flutter process`, that's what happened.

I'm still wondering, if we can just send a `r` to the 'screen' of the `flutter run` process?

Comment: you want to "hot reload" after every single key you type in your source .dart file?

Comment: Sorry about my fuzzy description, __"hot reload"__ after __.dart__ files `modified`, specifically, __"hot reload"__ after  `C+x s` in emacs.

Comment: see `flutter run --pid-file xxxxx` - the docs say: *"Specify a file to write the process id to. You can send SIGUSR1 to trigger a hot reload and SIGUSR2 to trigger a hot restart"*

Comment: Yep! this is what squashed my whole night yesterday, I found this solution on [Hot reload on save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340508/hot-reload-on-save), but I'm still confused about it, how does it work, and, what exactly should I do in my emacs?

Comment: so did you try to send `SIGUSR1` signal to that process?

Comment: Thanks for reminder...I realize that I am a lazy daydreaming guy...most of the time, working on it now, and I surely will update this question when I figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/angel_hot and https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/jaguar_hotreload are packages for hot-reload support for server-side development - to hot-reload on file changes.
 I'd expect this to work for Flutter as well.

You can also investigate the source and create a custom implementation.
The functionality is provided by the Dart observatory, a service built into the VM that you can connect to and that can be controlled over commands.

See also https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/runtime/vm/service/service.md

Comment: Thanks for helping! Your idea is great! But, it seems make my question more serious... I hope I can figure out the root question —— About the `flutter run` process's working principle, that I can deal similar problems beyond the limits of __flutter__ or __dart__, unlimited programming in an eyeful, haha~